# Why are these specific relocations supported in ARM Linux ELF module loader?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, elf

I'm referring to [linux/arch/arm/kernel/module.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/module.c). It seems to be an arbitrary subset of ARM ELF relocations. The [manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf) lists about 130 types of relocations. Most of which are "static" (why is the module loader dealing with static relocations instead of dynamic ones?) Is it because GCC only outputs these types? Or is there another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from the ARM Linux newsgroup:
http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2015-May/345809.html

> Under the configuration that is used to compile the kernel, only a
>   small subset of those relocations will ever be emitted by GCC. For
>   instance, since we are building without -fpic, many of the GOT and PLT
>   related ones will just never occur. And, since modules are not shared
>   libraries, but just partially linked object files, the runtime linking
>   that occurs actually resembles static linking more than it resembles
>   dynamic linking. (There is no support for things like lazy resolution
>   of jump targets or symbol preemption that the ELF standard defines.)
>   Also, while text relocations are typically avoided in userland since
>   they defeat sharing of code pages, this is not a problem in the
>   kernel.

So the reason is because GCC compilation of kernel modules will only output those relocations. I hope the GCC ARM maintainers know this...

Answer (score 0):

The ARM manual is meant for **all ELF** files; this includes 'C' compiler output before it is linked.  The 130 relocation type are for a variety of situations; The module loader only handles a sub-set of them.  For shared libraries and kernel modules, the final output doesn't know its final address, but it knows where all function/data will be relative to each other.  The absolute relocations need to be handled.

It does not try to link the '.o' files together to make a '.ko'.  This is done by `ld` which will handle many more of the relocation types but probably still not all of them.  The *specification* is meant to be globally complete.  There might be some type of relocations that aren't needed on targeted CPUs (like some really old ARM1 26 bit).

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking why the Linux specifically choose those to implement. The reason I ask was because I saw another system choose to implement the same subset of relocations and I was wondering if those engineers just took it from Linux or if there was some independent reason for choosing those relocations.

Comment: Because those are the ones that you need to implement if you relocate the base of an image.  Relative things do not need to be relocated.